# Usage of super in singleton

Tags: python, singleton

```
class Singleton(object):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
      if not hasattr(cls, '_instance'):
        orig = super(Singleton, cls)
        cls._instance = orig.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
      return cls._instance
```

Can someone give detailed explanation of what happens here >> super(Singleton, cls) 
for what cls argument is passed?

Comment: maybe this will help?
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Probably this will help? http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: This idiom is mentioned in the docs for [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), though without much explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cls` attribute passed in to the `__new__` method is a reference to the `Singleton` class (`cls == Singleton`), but if you subclassed `Singleton` and instantiated that subclass, `cls` would be a reference to the subclass instead.

`super` needs to know both the current class (`Singleton`) and the subclass whose class hierarchy it's traversing (`cls`) to compute the next class in the class hierarchy, but in your case they're always the same since `Singleton` does not have any subclasses.

To elaborate on why it is necessary to pass `cls`, let's assume that these classes all have simple pass-through `__new__` methods that simply call their super methods and return the result.

```
class A(object): pass
class B(object): pass
class C(A, B): pass
```

Then `C.__new__` calls `super(C, cls).__new__`, which is equivalent to `A.__new__`. Now here you want `super(A, cls).__new__` to be equivalent to `B.__new__`, not `object.__new__`. But the only way `super` can find that out is by being told that the start was at `C`, not at `A`.

Since in your case the only superclass is `object`, `orig.__new__` is equivalent to `object.__new__`, and it's passed `cls` so that it will know what class it should instantiate.

Comment: @loki Could you please rephrase the question? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.